# Process with query "SSISDB.catalog.start_execution;1" getting suspended

Tags: logging, ssis, process, suspend

we have one parent package which is executing some other packages in a sequence.
everytime when we run the job to execute parentpackage. one of the child package takes lot of time like 4 hours or 5 hours. and its random. its not for same package everytime.

**when i check using sp_who2 there is one process which is suspended and the query of that process is:**

> SSISDB.catalog.start_execution;1

and then whatever is the next task in the execution, the process for query of that task is also suspended.

we have Retention window of SSISDB only 7 days and the size of DB is also 9000MB only. but still why this process is going in suspended mode. that out of my knowledge.

anyone encountered this kind of issue? is there any solution to it. or is there any setting i could check for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this exact same issue on SQL 2016 SP1. Packages (built with VS2015 Upd 3 and targeted at SQL 2016) until last week ran fine and now taking hours, with some level of randomness to which one takes a long time. No other significant changes to the server, packages or databases since it used to run normally.

Update - Ended up being a lookup component issue. Looked through the "All messages" in standard reports on the catalog execution. A few duplicate lookup keys had crept into the data source... and that look up was failing over and over. with messages like this -

'*The buffer manager failed a memory allocation call for 5570320 bytes, but was unable to swap out any buffers to relieve memory pressure. 88 buffers were considered and 72 were locked. Either not enough memory is available to the pipeline because not enough are installed, other processes were using it, or too many buffers are locked.*'
and
'*Buffer manager allocated [X] megabyte(s) in [Y] physical buffer(s)*'

The execution report was 500 pages long, mostly with these messages repeated over and over in a loop with a gradual increase in the X and Y values. HTH